# Trying to render avatar image over a signature image with PHP

Tags: php

I am making a dynamic signature generator and I would like to add a avatar image in part of the signature. How would I do this as well as sizing down the image?

Comment: You should check out [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). You can check if its enabled with: `phpinfo()`

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work.. The Avatar img is not showing on the background.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/X7qLQ7Hw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

I have 2 images:

1. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/2e/9e/d12e9ecd9f4c4e45dafa5880c7d99c73.jpg
2. http://cf.juggle-images.com/matte/white/280x280/php-1-logo-primary.jpg

Steps:

1. Set the content type header - in this case image/jpg
2. Create new canvas, width: 720, height: 637
3. Create two new images from file or URL, $icon1 & $icon2
4. Copy part of $icon1 to $canvas
5. Copy and resize part of $icon2 to $can
6. Output image to browser

---

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(720,  637);
$icon1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/2e/9e/d12e9ecd9f4c4e45dafa5880c7d99c73.jpg');
$icon2 = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://cf.juggle-images.com/matte/white/280x280/php-1-logo-primary.jpg');

//add 2 source images
imagecopy($canvas, $icon1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 720,  637);
imagecopyresized($canvas, $icon2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 280, 280);

//Output image to browser
imagejpeg($canvas);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by copying one image on the other, with some resampling (to make the avatar smaller, if desired.).

PHP must have GD libs included, if not, make sure you have support for GD, otherwise you cannot use the functions.

Check your GD support: [function.gd-info.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php)

Then start reading here:

[function.imagecopy.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)

or here: [function.imagecopyresampled.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work.. The Avatar img is not showing on the background.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/X7qLQ7Hw